# How to make the compiler process this function?

Tags: c, compilation

I use a function in all of my code that turns a string literal such as `"0;1;6"` into a double value (in this case 0.125). The function, `double doztof(const char *string)` does this by calling several other of my functions and sscanf(). I naively expected the compiler to run the function and replace the call with the constant result, by which I mean `doztof("0;2;3")` will always yield a constant value of 0.1875, however neither compiler I use does this, and when used in a loop I end up with sscanf() running every single time to process the same constant string literal over and over.

Why would the compiler not optimise this out? Doesn't a string literal passed as a `const` indicate clearly enough that it will never change and that it's safe to optimise out? What else am I missing? Here's the full relevant code:

```
char *skip_string(const char *string, const char *skipstring)       // skipstring must be terminated by a %n
{
    int n=0;
    sscanf(string, skipstring, &n);
    return &string[n];
}

char *skip_whitespace(const char *string)
{
    return skip_string(string, " %n");
}

char *string_parse_fractional_12(const char *string, double *v)
{
    int i, n=0, ret=1, count=0, neg=0;
    double divisor=1., digit;
    char *p = string;

    *v = 0.;

    p = skip_whitespace(p);

    if (p[0] == '-')
    {
        neg = 1;
        p++;
    }

    for (i=0; i<20 && ret==1; i++)
    {
        n=0;
        ret = sscanf(p, "%lf%n", &digit, &n);
        p = &p[n];
        if (ret==1)
        {
            count++;
            *v += digit / divisor;
            divisor *= 12.;
        }

        n=0;
        sscanf(p, ";%n", &n);
        p = &p[n];

        if (p[0]==' ' || p[0]=='\t')    // detect whitespace so that the next sscanf avoids reading the numbers after the whitespace
            ret = 0;
    }

    if (count==0)
        return string;

    if (neg)
        *v = -*v;

    return p;
}

double doztof(const char *string)
{
    double v;
    string_parse_fractional_12(string, &v);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Where's the macro? I don't see any pre-processor code here. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Oops, I guess I used the wrong word. What do you call the part of the compiler that evaluates things like this?

Comment: You expect too much from the optimizer. It's not an arbitrary C execution engine.

Comment: Wow I genuinely had no idea that compilers weren't even supposed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Constant folding" or "constant propagation" would be the term to describe such an optimization, if it existed. But it applies to much simpler things, like

```
int x = 6 / 2;
int y = strlen("foo");
```

Your function is insanely complicated compared to any reasonable expectation of constant folding. If a compiler did compile-time evaluation of even a single call to `sscanf` I'd be very impressed.

Comment: Oh wow this is so disappointing, I really thought the compiler could evaluate the output of any function as long as everything involved was constant.